# Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::hasAnyUnit does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

i want to show checked state from database, when i adding `{{ $mod->hasAnyUnit($unit->kd_unit)?'checked':'' }}` on view, i got error

i have units table, like a role table:

```
-------------------
id | kd_unit | name
-------------------
1  | 01      | A
2  | 02      | B
2  | 03      | C
-------------------
```

And 2nd is rs table, like a users table:

```
-------------------
id | kd_rs| name
-------------------
1  | 01   | ASD
2  | 02   | ZXC
-------------------
```

And 3rd is mod table, like a role_user:

```
-------------------
id | kd_rs| kd_unit
-------------------
1  | 01   | 01
2  | 01   | 02
3  | 01   | 03
-------------------
```

My Model from mod table:

```
class TManagerOnDuty extends Model
{
    public function units() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Unit', 'kd_unit', 'kd_unit');
    }

    public function hasAnyUnits($units) {
        return null !== $this->units()->whereIn('kd_unit', $units)->first();
    }

    public function hasAnyUnit($unit) {
        return null !== $this->units()->where('kd_unit', $unit)->first();
    }
}
```

My Controller:

```
class ManagerOnDutyController extends Controller
{
  public function edit($kd_rs)
    {
        $units = Unit::orderBy('nm_unit', 'asc')->where('is_active', true)->get();
        $mod = TManagerOnDuty::where('kd_rs', $kd_rs)->get(); 
        return view('layouts.manageronduty.edit')->with([
            'mod'   => $mod,
            'units' => $units,
            'kd_rs' => $kd_rs
        ]);
    }
}
```

My view:

```
@foreach($units as $unit)
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-3">
        <input name="unitRS[]" value="{{$unit->kd_unit}}" {{ $mod->hasAnyUnit($unit->kd_unit)?'checked':'' }} id="customCheck{{$unit->kd_unit}}" class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck{{$unit->kd_unit}}">{{$unit->nm_unit}}</label>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

My error:
[image]

My expected:
[image]

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Comment: wait, i will added my error picture

Comment: @Fenz check what are you getting in `$mod` by doing `dd($mod);`

Comment: @PrashantDeshmukh..... this is result for dd($mod) [dd-image](https://pasteboard.co/IOeFy2T.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
$mod = TManagerOnDuty::where('kd_rs', $kd_rs)->first();
```

in your controller as get returns the set of object and you can not call your `hasAnyUnit()` from that set so first call a single object from you query and than chained it with **hasAnyUnit()**

Comment: After change $mod = .... i got error like this:
[link](https://pasteboard.co/IOexfFn.png)